# Generate random number between 0000 and 9999

Tags: java

I need to generate a 4 digit number from 0000 to 9999 and I can't seem to do so. I have this code, but it will generate 762 sometime, and I can't let it do that. I do need to use these methods though to generate it.

```
private java.util.Random rndGenerator = new java.util.Random();
private int randomValue;
public final static int NUMBER_OF_VALUES = 9999;


public GuessRandomValue() {
    randomValue = rndGenerator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_VALUES);
}


public void setAnswer() {
    randomValue = rndGenerator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_VALUES);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to change the random code; you need to change how you print it out.

Comment: what's the problem? 762 is in the given interval. Do you need left zeros? like: 0762?

Comment: Why do you hate 762? It's like one of my favorite numbers.

Comment: (I think you also need to add `1` as well.)

Comment: @DaveNewton I believe the fix is to set `NUMBER_OF_VALUES` to 10000, since 0 is a legal value for `randomValue`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to format your random value using the expression

```
String.format("%04d", randomValue);
```

If `randomValue` is 762, the call to `String.format` returns "0762", as desired.

---

EDIT: In response to comment below

Please leave `randomValue` as an integer.  You only want to use this code for user interaction i.e. formatting.  So to print `randomValue` you would use

```
System.out.printf("%04d\n", randomValue);
```

and you should use `String.format` if there is any part of the program that needs to keep a string for user interaction, but there is no need to change the way you store `randomValue`.

To compare what the user types in to `randomValue`, you can use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).  So you can use

```
int testValue;
try {
    testValue = Integer.parseInt(inputLine, 10);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // The user typed in something that isn't a number.  Alert the user somehow, and make
    // him or her try again
}
```

to get the typed-in value as an int, and just compare `testValue` and `randomValue` with ==.

Comment: Or printf. But you'd want `%04d`.

Comment: Is there anyway to leave it as an integer? For example, my program generates a number 0000-9999 then I input numbers trying to guess it.